# how to destroy lock object created by threading.Lock()?

Tags: python, multithreading

how to destroy lock object created by threading.Lock()? For example,

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import threading

dict = {}

dict['a']=threading.Lock()
dict['b']=threading.Lock()

def myfunc(group, i, lck):
    with lck:
        print "group %s sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % (group, i)
        time.sleep(5)
        print "finished sleeping from thread %d" % i

for i in range(5):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=('a', i, dict['a']))
    t.start()

for i in range(5):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=('b', i, dict['b']))
    t.start()
```

How do  I  destroy lock object in dict['b']?

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy"?

Comment: What do you mean by the word "destroy lock"?   A Lock object can be released using release() method of Lock class.

Comment: I was trying to delete the lock object to avoid memory leak. Is that possible?

Comment: Python automatically takes care of those things. Once nothing refers to the object, it is deallocated.

Comment: If my code is a daemon, I don't see how Python can "automatically takes care of those things".

Comment: Python implementations use *garbage collectors*, no need to worry.

Comment: If you really want you can `del dict['b']`. Assuming that this is the only reference to the lock object, the lock will then be eligible for garbage collection. Lock objects aren't big, and you only have 2 of them, so you shouldn't be concerned about memory use.

Comment: @johnsam I don't see how running it as a daemon changes anything. Whether it's daemon or not, it's running within a Python virtual machine. You stop referencing an object, then it's gone. To deal with reference cycles, there's also a GC which in special cases can be controlled via module `gc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll move this part up front because it's probably the most important.

Do you have some meaningful reason to be checking back in on the lock object referenced by `dct['a']`?  If you don't, well... then either don't store it in a dict in the first place, or just manually `del dct['a']` when you know you don't care about it any more.  Doing that simply deletes the *reference* to the lock held by your dict, not the object itself.

```
for i in range(5):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=('a', i, dct['a']))
    t.start()

# some more operations that use dct['a'] would probably happen here,
# else why did we put it there in the first place...
del dct['a']
```

Again to stress it, just because you `del` it out of this dictionary only means that you delete that particular reference to the object.  Only once all of your threads exit will there be no extant references, allowing gc to actually destroy the object.

On to some deeper discussion of what to do if you need to actually keep "checking in" on this lock object in your main thread.

---

> How do I destroy lock object in dict['b']?

Don't, at least not manually - let python's gc do that for you.  You need to work one level higher - manage your *references*.

If you want to keep a collection of `Lock` objects around, make it a collection of `weakref`s.  Python's garbage collector works by doing reference counting, and by only storing weakrefs you don't block the gc from doing its thing.  Example:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import threading
import weakref

dct = {}

def myfunc(group, i, lck):
    if callable(lck):
        #lck is a weakref, get the actual lock from it
        lck = lck()
    with lck:
        print "group %s sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % (group, i)
        time.sleep(5)
        print "finished sleeping from thread %d" % i

for i in range(5):
    lock = dct.get('a', threading.Lock())
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=('a', i, lock))
    if 'a' not in dct:
        dct['a'] = weakref.ref(lock)
    t.start()

while dct['a']():
    print 'lock still alive'
    time.sleep(3)

print 'lock is dead, jim'
```

output:

```
ben@nixbox:~$ python threadtest.py 
group a sleeping 5 sec from thread 0
lock still alive
lock still alive
finished sleeping from thread 0
group a sleeping 5 sec from thread 1
lock still alive
...
lock still alive
finished sleeping from thread 4
lock is dead, jim
```

Once a `Lock` is no longer (strongly) referenced by any thread, it is garbage collected (immediately, in cpython, possibly later in other python implementations).  Some notes:

- Don't name dicts `dict`.  Masks the built-in.
- I technically have a slight race condition in my above code - I depend on the first thread staying alive long enough for the second thread to start.  Obviously with a giant `sleep(5)` in there this is a nonissue, but a more sophisticated reference management strategy might be needed for extremely short-lived threads.
- While the `while dct['a']():` block at the bottom of the main thread seems analogous to a `join()` call, in practice don't depend on GC behavior to manage program control.  People can mess with the `gc`, or even run your code on a flavor of python that uses a gc strategy other than refcounting.
- Note that even after the lock to which the weakref refers gets GC'd, you still have a `weakref` object sitting in your dict.  Even though stale ones just point to `None`, you still will want to periodically go through and clean them out if your program is particularly long-lived.

Comment: Yes I do have need to share a lock such as dct['a'] with a group of thread. And ct['b'] with another group of thread. Use weakref and constantly clean the dct when it becomes None makes sense.

Comment: Followed a similar approach using weakref as suggested here. But getting the following errors:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'release' (First time)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'acquire' (Afterwards)